# Right way to dynamically allocate memory for list of structs in c

Tags: c, linked-list, call-graph

I have a structure containing edges:

```c
struct edges {
  int fromNodeID; 
  int toNodeID; 
  int edgeLabel;
};
```

And a structure containing a list of those tuples called graph:

```c
struct graph {
  struct edges* Edges;
};
```

In the function below am trying to initialize the `struct graph` to a pointer but I am not exactly sure how best to go about it. Seems like the array of edges is what should be dynamically allocated with the `totalNumberOfEdges`. I am not sure if in the graph struct I should store an array of pointers to edges or an array of edges.

```c
void Allocate(unsigned long totalNumberOfEdges) {
  struct graph *Database = malloc(sizeof(struct graph), totalNumberOfEdges);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two different allocations:

```c
struct graph *g = malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
g->edges = malloc(totalNumberOfEdges * sizeof(struct edge));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want your `Allocate` method to return the pointer to the newly-allocated memory, so first thing to do is change the function prototype to

```
struct graph *Allocate( unsigned long totalNumberOfEdges )
{
```

Then, you need to allocate the `struct graph` instance:

```
  struct graph *Database = malloc( sizeof *Database );
```

`sizeof *Database` yields the same result as `sizeof (struct graph)`, and it means you don't have to repeat type information.

Once you've verified that the `struct graph` instance has been properly allocated, then you allocate the `Edges` array:

```
  if ( Database )
    Database->Edges = malloc( sizeof *Database->Edges * totalNumberOfEdges );
```

Again, `sizeof *Database->Edges` yields the same result as `sizeof (struct edges)`.

Then all you need to do is return the newly-allocated object:

```
  return Database;
}
```

When you deallocate the graph, you'll want to do it in reverse order.  You'll probably want to write a `Deallocate` function to encapsulate that:

```
void Deallocate ( struct graph *Database )
{
  free( Database->Edges ); 
  free( Database );
}
```

And you'd call these as:

```
 struct graph *g = Allocate( numEdges );
 
 // do stuff with g

 Deallocate( g );
```